# What does this regex mean?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, regular-expression, quoting

I was working on the conversion of Unix newline to Windows newline. I tried to unix2dos but it gave me some binary error, so I looked it up and stumbled upon this regex

```
sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" input.txt > output.txt
```

This regex is working but I have got no clue, how is it working? Obviously I am trying to interpret it through this form

```
sed 's/a/b/'
```

Here

> a refers $'" which I don't understand.
>   and b refers `echo \\\r` which means '\r'

Also I don't understand why/how combination of single and double quote is being used? Can anyone explain this regular expression to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `$'"`

```
's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/" == "s/\$/`echo \\\r`/"
```

But the regex author just liked to escape `$` via single quote.

You can combine such escaping in any way you like.

So your regex it just appends `\r` to the end of the line.

update. Initially it wasn't clear from question that it uses `echo \\\r` instead of just echo \\\r.
There is no need to use `echo` here. You can just do it directly in sed:

```
sed 's/$/\r/'
```

Comment: Ok, Can't I use '\r' directly instead of using it with echo.

Comment: @JoeDimaggio You can use it directly. Initially \` symbol was hidden in your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Wow from that regex to this regex! :D. One more question though, It seems like the line-break in windows in \r\nEOL. But I feel like this regex will give /n\rEOL. so what am I missing here?

Comment: @JoeDimaggio actually in `sed` `\n` is outside working pattern ( except cases when several lines are in the buffer, but even in that case the last `\n` will be outside the buffer ) and `\r` will appear just before `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

That's some complex quoting. The argument to `sed` is built up from two parts. First, there's `'s/$'`, a single-quoted string literal, yielding the characters `s/$`. Then there's a double-quoted string, which contains the command substitution `` `echo \\\r` ``. This runs the command `echo \r`, which depending on the shell either prints `\r` or a CR character. (The text printed by `echo` ends in a newline, but the command substitution eats it up.) In order for this command to have the desired effect, you must be on a system where `echo \r` prints a CR character, which I'll represent here as `␍`.

The argument to sed is thus `s/$/␍/`. This replaces every match of the regular expression `$` by the string `␍`. The regex `$` matches the empty string, but only at the end of a line, so this sed command appends a CR to every line. Since a Unix line ends with LF while a Windows line ends with CR+LF, this transforms Unix line endings into Windows line endings.

GNU sed, but not other versions, understand backslash escapes such as `\r`. So with GNU sed you can write `sed 's/$/\r/'`. However, this doesn't work with other sed implementations (BSD, Solaris, …). `echo \r` isn't very portable either. A portable solution is to use `tr`, which has backslash escapes as a standard.

```
sed "$(echo 's/$/@/' | tr '@' '\r')"
```